# Imbedding a local URL in a google site

Tags: google-sites-2016

I am a complete newbie to Google sites editing. I am trying to create my personal page with my publications' list so that the visitor can download a PDF copy of each referenced paper. For instance, one reference could look like:

> Theory of Nothing, John Unknown, Unknown Publishing House, 2020.

I would like the "Theory of Nothing" title to become a link to the PDF file which is already in my Google Drive.  I tried to use the "insert link" option, but I don't know what link to insert. I tried also to use the external link of my PDF file, but it doesn't work.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you insert the link from Google Drive? Right click file > Get shareable link.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on your GDrive settings, you might want to try: Right click file > Share > Get shareable link (top right) > set Anyone with the link can view (depending on what you want)

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Alright, solution was - just insert from Google Drive. Right click a file in Google Drive > Get Shareable Link, and paste that link.