# Imbedding a local URL (HTML file) in a google site

Tags: plotly, google-sites

I have an HTML file created from plotly express. Here is the code which works fine:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    scatter_plot()
    return


def scatter_plot():
    ''' make a scatter plot with plotly '''
    # x and y given as array_like objects
    fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
    # fig.show()
    fig.write_html('test_plotly_figure.html', auto_open=True)
    return


# main guard idiom
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

It is saved in my google drive (and i can view the HTML file with the chart in my browser).

I can also embed the whole HTML file as a script and view on a google site. However, this means that i cannot change the data...

I actually **want to point to the HTML file** and have it open in the google site.

I tried this: [Imbedding a local URL in a google site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258568/imbedding-a-local-url-in-a-google-site)
but it does not work for HTML files since it shows the text of the document script and not the plotly chart (HTML doc).

How can i embed the HTML into the google site please ?